# Mongoose schema validate array with defined values

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, joi

I am new to mongoose and trying to validate array with predefined values like enum.
Below is my schema

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
language:{
    type:[String],  
    enum : ['Hindi','English','Gujarati','Marathi'], 
    required:true
}
});
```

Below is the JOI schema used to validate array values

```
const schema = { 
 language:Joi.array().min(1).required()  
};
```

How do I validate so that I can save the Language field as an array in mongodb.

Below is the valid json array to post

```
 {"language":["Hindi","English"] }
```

Below is the invalid json and it should not validate the schema.

```
 {"language":["French","Spanish","English"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.valid()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.0/API.md#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal) in `.items()`.

```
const schema = { 
  language: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.string().valid(['Hindi', 'English']))  // only allow(valid) 'Hindi' or 'English' items in array
    .min(1).required()
};
```

Comment: Its working but in that case its expecting only one value. I am getting this as error message ""language" must be one of [Hindi, English, Gujarati, Marathi]". I want to pass array of values not just one

Comment: you can omit `.min(1)` if you want multiple valid items

Comment: just ignore above comment. :) do you have specific `valid` languages and `invalid` languages? "English" in your example is included in `valid` and `invalid`. little bit confused.

Comment: this is valid array  ['Hindi','English','Gujarati','Marathi']. Anything without it should ends with an error.
For instance, If I post this json {"language":["French","Spanish","English"] } then, it should give me an error because French and Spanish are not in the array I defined.

Comment: so, you just allow only four languages, right? then just add 'Gujarati', 'Marathi' into valid array.

Answer (score 1):

As per the new version, I think we should use ... spread before an array. I was getting an error without ... operator.

```
private readonly groupSchema = object({
    name: string().required().alphanum().min(5).max(100),
    permissions: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(...['READ', 'WRITE', 'DELETE', 'SHARE', 'UPLOAD_FILES'])).min(1).unique().required()
});
```